# can't get value from yaml file in python

Tags: python, selenium, yaml

I could not understand where is my mistake. Everything seems ok but I can't get data from `yml` file.
Here is my `yml` file:

```
envdev:
  base_url: url
  user_name: user
  password: password
envprod:
  base_url: url
  user_name: user
  password: password
```

Here is my code in python:

```
 with open("../env.yml", 'r') as yamlfile:
        try:
            yaml_file = yaml.safe_load(yamlfile)
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            print(exc)
```

I am calling like this:

```
driver.get(yaml_file["envdev"]["base_url"])
```

And here is the error:

```
  >       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
E         (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.85)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:242: InvalidArgumentException
```

Comment: can you show us the original `yaml` file? seems there is an issue in URL formatting.

Comment: What is the 242 line of your code?

Comment: @Prophet 242 line comes from selenium package. `.../selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:242`

Comment: You are right, sorry

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strictyaml` to do so.

`yaml_file` will be a YAML object and `yaml_dict` a dictionary.

```
from strictyaml import load

with open("./tests/env.yml", "r") as yamlfile:
    yaml_file = load(yamlfile.read())

yaml_file["envdev"]["base_url"]
```

Transform to dictionary for nicer handling:

```
yaml_dict = yaml_file.data
yaml_dict["envdev"]["base_url"]
```